# How to set rowspan in pyqtgraph?

Tags: pyqtgraph

I want to set 3 PlotWidget items : wgt_simplePlot0, wgt_simplePlot1, wgt_simplePlot2.
`wgt_simplePlot0` is on top and I use `rowspan` option to make it 15 times taller then the others. But when I run the script, `wgt_simplePlot0` is the shortest. What is the problem?

[image]

I use Windows 10, Python 3.9 x64, Pyqtgraph 0.12.4/0.13.3

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtWidgets

class PlotterWin:
    def __init__(self):

        self.app        = pg.mkQApp()
        self.win        = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        gridLayout      = pg.LayoutWidget()     # https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/widgets/layoutwidget.html


        self.wgt_simplePlot0 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot0, row=0, col=0,  rowspan=15, colspan=10 )

        self.wgt_simplePlot1 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot1, row=16, col=0, rowspan=1, colspan=5 )

        self.wgt_simplePlot2 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot2, row=16, col=5, rowspan=1, colspan=5 )

        self.win.setCentralWidget(gridLayout)

        self.win.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plotter = PlotterWin()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve what you want with just grid layout. Qt is based around Size Policies.

Try this code instead. You can regulate how high is top plot by increasing `top_policy.verticalStretch(int)` value.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets


class PlotterWin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = pg.mkQApp()
        self.win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        gridLayout = pg.LayoutWidget()  # https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/widgets/layoutwidget.html

        top_policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy()
        top_policy.setVerticalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        top_policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        top_policy.setVerticalStretch(2)

        self.wgt_simplePlot0 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        self.wgt_simplePlot0.setSizePolicy(top_policy)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot0, row=0, col=0, colspan=2)

        bottom_policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy()
        bottom_policy.setVerticalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        bottom_policy.setHorizontalPolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Preferred)
        bottom_policy.setVerticalStretch(1)

        self.wgt_simplePlot1 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        self.wgt_simplePlot1.setSizePolicy(bottom_policy)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot1, row=1, col=0, colspan=1)

        self.wgt_simplePlot2 = PlotWidget(background='white')
        self.wgt_simplePlot2.setSizePolicy(bottom_policy)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.wgt_simplePlot2, row=1, col=1, colspan=1)

        self.win.setCentralWidget(gridLayout)

        self.win.show()
        self.app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    plotter = PlotterWin()
```